# Sleep or delay a Timer thread in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have been trying to create a delay of one or two seconds on a self repeating timer. This is how I create the timer:

```
currentThread = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(Movement.updatePosition), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

So the timer constantly runs the method updatePosition(). However, I have an if statement within that method where I would like to have the timer be delayed for a few seconds:

```
if distance <= respawnDistance * 0.1 {
    // Delay timer for 1 second     
}
```

And I was thinking that I could do this:

```
currentThread.invalidate()
```

And then just create another Timer that runs after 1 second, which leads to the reactivation of the previous timer. However, I think that would be inefficient if there is a way to sleep the current Timer?

Comment: You could use an infinite loop to call the updatePosition method, and just have a 1 second timer in there? This might not be the most efficient way...

Comment: I have to wonder what `updatePosition` does. If this is some kind of animation, use animation, not a timer.

Comment: All you need is a bool variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTimer` is not that accurate. Its maximum resolution is somewhere around 50 - 100ms. Anyhow, you can add a variable to control the firing of the timer:

```
var doNotUpdate = false

if distance <= respawnDistance * 0.1 {
    doNotUpdate = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        doNotUpdate = false
    }
}

func updatePosition() {
    if doNotUpdate { return }

    // update your position
}
```

Comment: I have also noticed how timers are not accurate. Thanks